# Load css after a portion of HTML

Tags: html, css

I've created a loading screen for my website, which I want to immediately be rendered as soon as the page is opened, before any css is loaded. I thought that the best way to do this would be to put it before the `<head>` tag, so that the browser will only start to load CSS once it has rendered the laoding screen.

What happens though, is that the browser places everything in the head into the body, preventing my css from loading.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="LoadingScreen"><style>#LoadingScreen{ CSS ... }</style>
Loading
<script>var LSDate=Date.now();addEventListener("pageshow",()=>{var e=()=>{document.getElementById("LoadingScreen").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("LoadingScreen"))};Date.now()-LSDate>=500?e():setTimeout(e,Date.now()+500-Date.now())});</script></div>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
CSS includes here...
```

However, this gets parsed by the browser into this:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<title>Title</title>
CSS includes here, but not actually being included as they're not in the header
```

It seems to completely chop off both my head and my loading screen.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps could I add the HEAD to the document using Javascript at a later time?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<div>`s before the `<head>`

Comment: That is what I am asking, is it possible to get around this? Perhaps by adding the <head> to the document using Javascript?

Comment: TBH I don't even understand what you're trying to do. You have some sort of loading screen that you don't want your CSS to be applied to? This seems like a CSS issue in that your styling should be rewritten to not apply to whatever elements are on your loading screen. As it stands now though, your question feels like it's missing details.

Comment: I have a loading screen which I want to be rendered by the browser before it loads any CSS. This means placing it before the HEAD tag, which as you pointed out is not allowed. Is there a way to circumvent this, other than placing the HEAD tag into the document using Javascript which would be bad practise?

Comment: Yes, but what do you think is to be gained from rendering this tag before the browser loads any CSS?  I understand somewhat what it is you are trying to do, but not why.  That would be helpful-- I suspect that you have incorrect assumptions about how this will behave.

Comment: `this means placing it before the HEAD tag` - HTML does not work like that. It is not like some script that runs from top to button. `<head>` and `<body>` tags are specific areas for very different types of element. Everything that is rendered to the DOM is in the body. You should read a little more on HTML because this is a very basic structure which you should understand before moving on.

Comment: I wanted the loading screen to be shown to the user as soon as possible, meaning before any CSS is shown. I managed to fix this by loading the css asyncronously.